# Generate a PDF out of a HTML String and Display it in Swift

Tags: swift, pdfkit

I want to generate an PDF, from an HTML-String and display it. Further I want to share this PDF Document, with a *UIActivityViewController*. Is this possible, and how can I do that (if its possible).
Thanks for your time and maybe for your help
Boothosh